# Missing "C++ language standard" option in Visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to compile my project using `c++11` standard but that option in missing in my IDE.

[image]

I believe VS could show me the standard option like this

[image]

Comment: There is no option to target a version less than C++11.  They had to completely rewrite the legacy front-end in order to get compliant, making it C++03 compliant wasn't considered.  You don't get to choose until they started supporting C++17, in VS2017.  But note that this work [was not yet completed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c1114-core-language-features-in-vs-2013-and-the-nov-2013-ctp/) in 2013, updating your VS version is wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [option to set language standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019) was added in Visual Studio 2017.

It's just not possible with earlier versions.